# Qual a melhor forma de se trabalhar com filas em java?

Tags: java, algoritmo

Em quais cenários uma fila é necessária? Qual a vantagem de utilização desse algoritmo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conforme dito pelo @RHERWOLF em [sua resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/254105/64969), fila é uma estrutura de dados. Qual a diferença de uma estrutura de dados e um algoritmo?

Bem, um algoritmo é um conjunto finito de passos para fazer uma computação. Uma estrutura de dados compõe algoritmos (sim, no plural) e também um lugar para armazenar o estado atual dessa tal de estrutura.

Normalmente, um algoritmo tem como preocupação apenas sua execução atual. Ele simplesmente há para fazer aquele processamento e sair. Uma estrutura de dados já se preocupa em usos subsequentes dela mesma. Seu estado é variável.

Por exemplo, para atender ao que normalmente se chama de fila, você deve implementar uma regra chamada **FIFO**, *first in, first out* (primeiro a entrar, primeiro a sair).

Só pela leitura dessa regra se percebe que a estrutura de dados "fila" possui pelo menos duas operações: empurrar elementos para dentro dela, retirar elementos de dentro. Em nenhum momento desse "contrato" se fala em tamanho de fila, então isso seria uma adição sua. Poderia até mesmo chamar por outro nome, "fila mensurável".

Sobre as operações da fila, você normalmente encontra os seguintes termos:

- *push* ou *enqueue*: para adicionar/empurrar elementos
- *pop* ou *dequeue*: para remover elementos

> Qual a melhor forma de se trabalhar com filas em Java?

Então, a melhor forma de se usar uma fila é quando ela se adequa ao seu problema. É comum você usar já as classes já provenientes da biblioteca padrão porque elas são "boas o suficiente". Mas sempre é possível ter sua própria solução para filas caso encontre algum cenário que tornem as filas do sistema ruins.

Eu particularmente nem uso muito filas, elas normalmente não fazem parte do meu mundo de problemas no trabalho. Pilhas são mais comuns para mim.

Se você não precisa dessa garantia de ordem de chegada e saída, então você não necessita de uma fila. No meu trabalho, a estrutura mais comum que eu uso é a *bag*, é tipo um conjunto da matemática mas pode conter elementos repetidos.

> Em quais cenários uma fila é necessário?

Quando você precise armazenar dados e fazer subsequente resgate mantendo a restrição FIFO.

> **Adendo**: em quais situações elas não são necessárias?

1. Quando você não tem uma lista de valores
2. Quando você não tem a necessidade de armazenar esses valores

   - posso fazer análises estatísticas  de elementos unidimensionais  sem precisar armazenar cada indivíduo, atualizando seu desvio padrão e sua média para cada novo indivíduo que surge
3. Quando você precisa armazenar os valores, mas a ordem de resgate é irrelevante

   - por exemplo, somar os valores dos itens dentro do meu pedido; não necessito que esses itens sejam acessados na exata maneira como foram inseridos no pedido; contanto que passe por todos os itens, a ordem pode ser totalmente arbitrária
4. Quando a ordem de acesso precisa ser inverso à ordem de armazenamento

   - nesse caso em específico, você precisa de uma pilha, `LIFO`, "último a entrar, primeiro a sair"

> Qual a vantagem de se usar filas?

Quando você estiver lidando com um problema que exija filas, solucioná-los fica mais fácil.

Comment: Jefferson, `push` e `pop` são termos usados em pilha, já em fila se usa `enqueue` e `dequeue` e em listas não há uma convenção. Não sei o que você quis dizer no sexto parágrafo, mas dá uma corrigida, ok? Além disso, o "adendo" exclui muitas possibilidades de não necessidade, é melhor resumir: quando não precisa de armazenamento de dados ou não precisa de extração em ordem pelos primeiros, assim como pilha não é necessária quando não precisa de armazenamento de dados ou não precisa de extração em ordem pelos últimos.

Comment: Também pode explicar que estruturas de dados têm algoritmos para manipulá-las (algoritmo de inserção, retirada, acesso, etc), portanto estruturas não são algoritmos mas são associadas a algoritmos e em boa parte diferenciadas por isso. Tipo, em fundamentos da computação qual é a diferença de lista, fila e pilha? Os algoritmos de armazenamento, acesso e retirada, somente isso.

Comment: @RHERWOLF, sobre o seu segundo comentário, eu pensei que tinha ficado claro que estrutura de dados é composta de algoritmos e de também algo mais perene. Certeza que não ficou claro? Eu tenho a ótica do autor, então caso você com a ótica do leitor me falar que eu realmente pequei, vou tentar melhorar. Talvez até mesmo exemplificando com um modelo concreto...

Comment: @RHERWOLF,  sobre o seu primeiro comentário, você fez vários pontos. Então vou tentar responder cada ponto. (1) "`push` e `pop` são mais voltados para pilha": não se é por vício de linguagem, mas já vi em muitos pontos usando `push` e `pop` para filas também. Vou alterar minha resposta para por `push/enqueue` e `pop/dequeue`. (2) "não sei o que você quis dizer no sexto parágrafo": hmmm... qual o sexto parágrafo? Aquele que eu falo "sobre operações em lista"? Se for esse, foi erro meu mesmo, era para estar "sobre operações em fila"

Comment: (3) "resumir o adendo": obrigado pela sugestão. Acho que é importante ter os 4 itens que eu escrevi, mas uma visão reduzida e direta faz falta também.